# On Visual Studio Code, how do I specify my pytest.ini file for test discovery

Tags: visual-studio-code, pytest, vscode-python

I use `pytest` for testing. My test files reside in a subdirectory `tests` and they are named `Foo.py`, `Bar.py` instead of `test_Foo.py`, `TestFoo.py`, etc. So, to make sure `pytest` find them, I have a `pytest.ini` file in the root dir of the project with the following contents:

```
[pytest]
python_files=tests/*py
```

How to I specify the path to the `pytest.ini` file in Visual Studio Code so that the `vscode-python` plugin can correctly/successfully discover my test files? No matter what I try, I get `Test discovery failed`, with no reasons given.

Answer (score 16):

To set up VS Code to use a specific `pytest.ini` file, you need to do the following:

1. Open a **directory** in VS Code (`ctrl+k  >  ctrl+o`)
2. Select a **Python interpreter** (`ctrl+shift+p  >  Python: Select Interpreter  >  Python interpreter`)
3. Configure the **testing framework** you want to use, in this case **PyTest** (`ctrl+shift+p  >  Python: Configure Tests  >  Pytest  >  {pytest rootdir}`
4. Open the `settings.json` file generated inside the `.vscode/` directory that was created in your working directory (the one you chose in step 1)
5. Add the following setting to the file (it may already exist if you specified a `rootdir` when configuring pytest):

```py
    "python.testing.pytestArgs": [
        "-c",
        "/path/to/your/pytest.ini"
    ],
```

That's it! VS Code should be using the pytest.ini file you specify in the last argument. You can specify any CLI options you want there.

[Source](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/testing#_pytest-configuration-settings)

Answer (score -1):

Pytest requires the test function names to start with `test`  or ends with `test`.

The ini file instructs py.test to treat all *_test.py files as unit tests.

Comment: I know how to use `pytest.ini` files. What I don't know is how to tell Visual Studio Code where it is so that it can discover my tests. My question is specific to Visual Studio Code (see tag and question title).